# mysql fine specific order category

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

i have two table. order and product_order.
Order Table like bellow:

[image]

I want to get the orders, where some specific category products are added. Such my example i want to know which orders have not category_id 2, 3 and 4. here order_id: 3 has category_id: 3,4,7. But order_id: 4 has category_id: 5,7. So order_id: 3 not full-fill the requirement.
My main concern is that, find those orders which has no specific product category. if any order has multiple category, it will be not acceptable if those blocking category_d there are exist.

Actually i need the customer_id who orders other category products. if in a single order has both 3 and 5, we not allow him in this filtering list. we need to know who ordered products excluding category 2,3 and 4

Comment: Can you try reformatting your table for legibility

Comment: Are you dealing with a SQL table or an HTML table?  Is the above HTML being generated from a back end SQL table somewhere?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please check the table structure

Comment: There is no category_id here

Comment: second table has order_id and category_id

Answer (score 0):

Here can be your query according to my understanding:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.order_id
    FROM order o, order_category oc
WHERE
    o.order_id = oc.order_id
    AND
    oc.category_by NOT IN (2,3,4)
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: hi thanks, actually i need the customer_id who orders other category products. if in a single order has both 3 and 5, we not allow this filtering list. we need to know who ordered products excluding category 2,3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

You need post aggregation filtering

```
SELECT order_id FROM order_category  
GROUP BY  order_id  
HAVING SUM(category_by=2)=0 
AND SUM(category_by=3)=0 
AND SUM(category_by=4)=0
```